# Fine uploader calls onAllComplete twice

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

Fine uploader calls `onAllComplete` even at the page load (uploader loads previously uploaded files) when `session` from Initial File List is used.

If I keep it like that, an infinite loop will start, so I would like the `onAllComplete` to NOT be called at init ideally without need to use any flags.

I am using this code:

```
session: {
   endpoint: '/assets/inc/reappear-image-...'
},
callbacks: {
   onAllComplete: function (succeeded, failed) {
      //this happens to be called on init and then on save
      ...
```

Comment: without more code or a link the the actual library, there is no way to tell why the 'onAllComplete' is firing twice.  You could blindly use flags to control the double call, but like you said, you don't want to use flags.

Comment: @Kyle I assume 'onAllComplete' is fired when previously saved files are loaded, but I believe it should be fired only when new ones are uploaded. The version of Fine Uploader is 5.16.0 and the link is here for example https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/file-uploader/5.16.0-beta.0/jquery.fine-uploader/jquery.fine-uploader.js